# Moving unique_ptr constructed at lambda capture site into a vector fails

Tags: c++, lambda

Dummy code of what I was trying to do:

```cpp
auto test_foo = [foo_o1 = make_unique<Foo>(), &vectorOfFoo]() {
    auto foo_o2 = make_unique<Foo>();
    vectorOfFoo.push_back(std::move(foo_o2)); //COMPILES
    vectorOfFoo.push_back(std::move(foo_o1)); //ERROR: use of deleted function unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
};
```

Comment: Notice then than calling `test_foo` twice will `push_back` moved-from `foo_o1` (so `nullptr`).

Comment: Please always post the exact error message along with [mcve], that way it's obvious what the problem is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function-call operator of the lambda is const-qualified by default, so `foo_o1` that was copy-captured is non-modifiable inside of it.

You can mark the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as `mutable`:

> `mutable`: allows body to modify the objects captured by copy, and to call their non-const member functions

E.g.

```
auto test_foo = [foo_o1 = make_unique<Foo>(), &vectorOfFoo]() mutable {
    auto foo_o2 = make_unique<Foo>();
    vectorOfFoo.push_back(std::move(foo_o2)); //COMPILES
    vectorOfFoo.push_back(std::move(foo_o1)); //COMPILES
};
```